# Associative Arrays - accessing parameters

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following object and string variable passed in `vue`'s props:

**`catId`** :

```
"51bd55834e8d79bfd458ff8a156e3c11"
```

**`categories`** :

```
{
    "51bd55834e8d79bfd458ff8a156e3c11": {
        "header": "Header One",
        ".key": "51bd55834e8d79bfd458ff8a156e3c11"
    },
    "eb4312829f9c57b55727b4d8c6ca1ec7": {
        "typeId": "ba86f15d5b2126ac3d0ad39feeb5f400",
        "header": "Header Two",
        ".key": "eb4312829f9c57b55727b4d8c6ca1ec7"
    }
}
```

How can I access the `header` parameter of the given category?

I tried the following...

```
{{categories[this.catId].header}}
```

...but it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that you're using text interpolation with mustaches. In that case I don't think you need `this`. Try ..

```
{{categories['catId'].header}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work fine.

```js
var id = "51bd55834e8d79bfd458ff8a156e3c11"
var categories = {
    "51bd55834e8d79bfd458ff8a156e3c11": {
        "header": "Header One",
        ".key": "51bd55834e8d79bfd458ff8a156e3c11"
    },
    "eb4312829f9c57b55727b4d8c6ca1ec7": {
        "typeId": "ba86f15d5b2126ac3d0ad39feeb5f400",
        "header": "Header Two",
        ".key": "eb4312829f9c57b55727b4d8c6ca1ec7"
    }
};
console.log(categories[id].header);
```